# CSS :host alternative for normal dom

Tags: css, angular, dom, sass

I am using a shadow DOM in angular and I style the host in CSS by `:host` selector.

In Angular if I make `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` then I will be in normal DOM and `:host` selector will not work

What is alternative in CSS or SASS, etc to `:host` selector in normal DOM?

Why I need a workaround?

Because if I activate ViewEncapsulation.None for debugging purpose the :host in styles is ignored

Comment: "I am using a shadow DOM in angular " does mean what exactly?

Comment: Angular by default make #shadow in html

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/shadowdom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I am using a shadow DOM in angular " does mean what exactly? You're in normal DOM by default. There is no shadow DOM unless you use `ViewEncapsulation.Native`. The default merely emulates the shadow DOM.

There is nothing like a `:host` selector if you use `ViewEncapsulation.None`

You would need to explain what exact problem you try to solve for more concrete suggestions how to work around.

Comment: There is no such thin than `host` if you use `ViewEncapsulation.None`. I probably could help more if you provided more information about what actual problem you're trying to solve or why you think you ned `ViewEncapsulation.None` which you most likely don't.

Comment: if I activate ViewEncapsulation.None for debugging purpose the :host in styles is ignored

Comment: That's basically the purpose of `ViewEncapsulation.None`. There is no way to help you if you don't provide any information.